# Adding Banner ads to Ionic 2 apps

Tags: admob, angular, ionic2

i have been trying to add banner ads for the new ionic 2 apps but the ads are not showing up
i am doing it as shown here

http://pointdeveloper.com/ionic-2-banner-ads-with-admob-pro-plugin/

here is my app.js files code

```
import {App, Platform, Config} from 'ionic/ionic';
import {TabsPage} from './pages/tabs/tabs';


@App({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  // Check out the config API docs for more info
  // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
  config: {
     tabbarPlacement: 'bottom'
  }
})
export class MyApp {
  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    this.root = TabsPage;

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Do any necessary cordova or native calls here now that the platform is ready
      var admobid = {};
        // select the right Ad Id according to platform
        if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
            admobid = { // for Android
                banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/9375997553',
                interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/1657046752'
            };
        } else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            admobid = { // for iOS
                banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/4806197152',
                interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/7563979554'
            };
        } else {
            admobid = { // for Windows Phone
                banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/8878394753',
                interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/1355127956'
            };
        }

  if(window.AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( {
      adId:admobid.banner,
      isTesting:true, 
      position:AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER
     } );
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hey there i saw you are using my post here

http://pointdeveloper.com/ionic-2-banner-ads-with-admob-pro-plugin/

but what you need to do is to add **autoShow:true**

so in your code you need the following

```
  if(window.AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( {
      adId:admobid.banner,
      isTesting:true, 
      position:AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, 
      autoShow:true //this shows the ad
      } );
```

Answer (score 0):

i have also a problem, the banner works but the interstitial crash my app i don't know why..

I have to put something in my page ? like parameters or imports ?

Comment: followed this tutorial http://pointdeveloper.com/ionic-2-banner-ads-with-admob-pro-plugin/ and it worked no need to add any parameters